# How to connect clients to INTERNAL WSUS server but download the approved updates from Microsoft?

Tags: windows-8.1, group-policy, wsus

I have client-side targeting setup to handle some remote workstations on our network.  They VPN in from time to time -- so they can hit the internal WSUS server when they are connected.

I essentially want to set their Windows Update configuration via GPO to use internal WSUS, but to download the updates from the internet (Microsoft).  I'm assuming this is a very standard configuration, but my clients are still trying to download from the WSUS server.  Can I control this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open **WSUS Administration**
2. Click **Options**
3. Click **Update Files**
4. Select **Do not store updates locally; computers install updates from Microsoft Update**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939910%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I found the Microsoft page with the answer to the OP's request and updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, that was an edit worth a +1. :)